# How reliable is Lucene when counting hits/documents?

Tags: lucene

If a run a search: "+house +car" and returns 5,343,562 hits

Is that the exact number of documents I have, or it's an approximation.

If it's an approximation, is there a way to make it to return the extract number of documents that qualifies for a search query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exact.  What makes you think it's an approximation?

Comment: Does your boss has more cars and houses then 5,343,562. He should rather be right